# Two datetime item different when compared

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

I face a problem with datetime element.
I stored with a SP a `datetime` value (`lastwritetime`), I get it from a `FileInfo` element.

When I insert my data into my database, the value is good : 
[image]

I use this SP to insert my data :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_AddImageToCategory](
    @catID numeric(6,0),
    @newImageName varchar(50),
    @newImageJpgLoc varchar(255),
    @newImageTargaLoc varchar(255),
    @newImageIsInUse int,
    @dateCreation datetime,
    @dateexpiration datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @starttrancount int

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT
        IF @starttrancount = 0
            BEGIN TRAN ps_AddImageToCategory_tran
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ZIMG_Image] 
                  (CIMG_ID,
                   IMG_Name, 
                   IMG_Localisation, 
                   IMG_TargaFile, 
                   InUse, 
                   IMG_DateCreation,
                   IMG_DateExpiration)
            VALUES(@catID, 
                   @newImageName,
                   @newImageJpgLoc, 
                   @newImageTargaLoc, 
                   @newImageIsInUse,
                   @dateCreation,
                   @dateexpiration)
        IF @starttrancount = 0
            COMMIT TRAN ps_AddImageToCategory_tran
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH     
        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN ps_AddImageToCategory_tran
            EXECUTE [dbo].[isp_LogError]
        END
        EXECUTE [dbo].[isp_RaiseError]
    END CATCH
END
```

And I call my SP with this code :

```
public bool InsertZimgImage(ZIMG_Image imageToInsert)
{
    using (var conn = InitSqlConnection())
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("ps_AddImageToCategory", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catID", imageToInsert.CIMG_ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newImageName", imageToInsert.IMG_Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newImageJpgLoc", imageToInsert.IMG_Localisation);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newImageTargaLoc", imageToInsert.IMG_TargaFile);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newImageIsInUse", (imageToInsert.InUse ? 1 : 0));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateCreation", imageToInsert.IMG_DateCreation);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateexpiration", imageToInsert.IMG_DateExpiration);
        conn.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After that, I check every hour if the `lastwritetime` of my file is different from the value in the database. If it's différents, I update the database and do some operations.

My bug is when I proceed my `DateTime.Compare` operation.
In fact data values are never the same. Even if we do not edit the file.
My first screenshot is the debug-value of my datetime inserted in database :

[image]

And the second screenshot is about the datetime in my `FileInfo` element :

[image]

Of course I see the value `Hour`,  `Kind` and `Ticks` who are different, but I can't explain why.
For your information, I all time use the object `DateTime` in my C# program, and I do no alter the `DateTime` item send to my SP.
It looks like there is a lost of data when inserted in the DB

I hope someone could explain to me why I have this gap between two same dates and how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: How did you store the value? Please show your code. What time zone are you in? I suspect that the local time may be being converted to UTC, but it's hard to know without more details. Additionally, I believe a SQL server datetime value only has precision to milliseconds.

Comment: Post edited with more informations

Comment: an hour difference, this must be UTC related

Comment: You still haven't shown how you're calling your stored procedure. You should be able to write a short but complete program that just obtains a `DateTime` value, stores it, then retrieves it, logging both.

Comment: What type of date field is this being stored into? `smalldatetime`, `datetime`?

Comment: `DateTime.Kind` is different. One it is set to `Local` and the other to `Unknown`. The two date times will therefore come back as not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mixture of 2 things happening here

1. The created date of your file has an implicit timezone - indicated by the `Kind=Local`, you lose that information when you stash the date away in a database.
2. [`datetime` values in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187819.aspx) have an accuracy rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. This explains why 762 milliseconds becomes 763.

Therefore you will never get equality between these dates.

The workaround is, again, twofold

1. Chose to explicitly store UTC date/times, which gets rid of all timezone issues.
2. When comparing dates, only compare the day, month, year, hour, minute & second components. Ignore the milliseconds when retrieving a datetime from a database.

Comment: Ok thanks, I used the `LastWriteTimeUtc` to get and save data. Do you have a sample for a good datetime comparaison without milliseconds ?

Comment: @XavierWOLFF, create two datetimes from the Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute, Seconds from each datetime and then compare.

Comment: I fixed it with an extension of DateTime and UTC types